# Google app engine, full text search for empty (None) field

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I'd like to use Google AppEngine full text search to search for items in an index that have their logo set to None

tried
"NOT logo_url:''"

is there any way I write such a query, or do I have to add another property which is has_logo?

Answer (score 2):

You can not filter by non existing values by nature of full text search indexes.

You would need to create a column/property "no_logo" to be able to do this.

As an option you can define some default for empty values. For example just a string `"None"`. Then search like:

```
logo_url: None
```

That is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

NOT logo_url: Null